# How to change the profile picture using bootstrap controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am changing the user profile picture on `onclick()` event. it is getting

saved in the iis server but when it is not reflecting the aspx page. when i log out and log in again. Its getting updated.
here is my code :

**Default.aspx**

```
 <input type="file" id="userPicFileUpload" runat="server" />
        <button runat="server" class="btn btn-info editable-submit" id="btnChangeUserPic" onclick="ChangeUserPic();">Change</button>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void btnChangeUserPic2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");                            
            HttpPostedFile File = userPicFileUpload.PostedFile;
            string fileExtn = Path.GetExtension(File.FileName).ToLower();
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File.FileName);               
            File.SaveAs(filename);
            lblStatus.Visible = true;
            lblStatus.Text = "Profile picture changed successfully !!";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        }

    }
```

its not getting refreshed after uploading the picture.Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not changing the image after saving the image.

```
protected void btnChangeUserPic2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");                            
        HttpPostedFile File = userPicFileUpload.PostedFile;
        string fileExtn = Path.GetExtension(File.FileName).ToLower();
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File.FileName);               
        File.SaveAs(filename);
        lblStatus.Visible = true;
        lblStatus.Text = "Profile picture changed successfully !!";
        profilepic.ImageUrl=filePath+filename;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {               
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply replace your button with asp button and it works...

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` is a client side markup for a client side button.

To be able to use the buttons callback, you need an `<asp:Button>` or similar, that is bound to the btnClick. The `<asp:Button>` is a serverside control, that binds with the codebehind, but produces a ClientSide html button, that will call the server when clicked.

Else you need to start playing with the ScriptManager.

To avoid repeating the answer to a well known "problem", Ill send you to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET

Where everything about making a fileupload with ASP.NET WebForms is explained